# Inequality for the division of expectations of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis, expected-value

This strongly relates to my other [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307335/jensens-inequality-for-the-difference-of-conditional-expectations), but I am gonna formulate it in a simpler and more general way.
Suppose $X$ is a real random variable, $\phi(x)$ is a convex function and the functions $g$, $f$ are such that $g(x) \le  f(x)\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Does the following inequality hold?\begin{equation}
 \frac{\phi\big(E[f(X)]\big)}{\phi\big(E[g(X)]\big)}\le \frac{E\big[\phi\big(f(X)\big)\big]}{E\big[\phi\big(g(X)\big)\big]}
\end{equation}
The problem here is that, because of Jensen's Inequality, both the enumerator and the denominator grow when $\phi$ is inside the expectations. So the change in magnitude of the enumerator has to be larger than the demoninator's.
So for example let $X\in\{1,2\}$ and $p=0.5$ for both events. Let $\phi(x)=e^x,\ g(x)=x,\ f(x)=x+1$. In this case both sides of the equation work out to be the same.
I tried out some other examples with simple two or three-valued r.v. and the inequality always held.
My intuition for this is, since $\phi$ is convex, the larger function causes a larger change in magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true. For example if $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ and $\phi $ is strictly convex with  $\phi (1)=1$ ( say $\phi (x)=e^{x}-e+1$) then  the inequality goes in the opposite direction and you can easily give examples where the reverse inequality is strict.

Comment: I calculated some examples with the functions you suggested and also found some counterexamples. Are there any assumptions on the functions I could make such that the inequality holds in way I suggested?

Comment: I cannot think  of any simple useful condition for the inequality to hold. You have inequalities for the numerator and the denominator separately but it is hard to find conditions for the ratios to satisfy this inequality.

Comment: Say we're in the special case $\phi(x)=e^x,\ f(x)=x,\ g(x)=min(x,K)$, where $K>0$ is a constant and $X\ge 0$. How can I try to prove this or find a counterexample? I appreciate your help!